# Ajax fetch pass values to next fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to get some data from api, untill now i have this:

```
var sp = [];
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.gettingLeagues.com/api/v1/json/1/all_leagues.php',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function() {
              $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                sp.push(v.idLeague);
              });
            });
        }
    });

var $orders = $('#prediction'); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.gettingMatchesByLeague.com/api/v1/json/1/eventsnextleague.php?id='+sp+',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function() {
              $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                console.log(v);
                $orders.append('<li class='+v.idEvent+'>'+v.strEvent+'</li>');
              });
            });
        }
    });
```

I am trying to achive to get all leagues id and pass it to second fetch football  matches by league id from first fetch.

Comment: Instead of pushing these values to an array, have you tried passing them as a parameter in a function that wraps the second fetch?

Comment: Put the second part into a then callback, `$.ajax(...).then((data)=>{ $.ajax(...) })`